# Different image sizes move divs down asymmetrically

Tags: html, css

I have the following going on:

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 content-column">
            <img class="btn-center btn-desktop" src="images/buttons/btn-desktop.svg" alt="desktop button">
            <h2 class="btn-desktop-headline">Desktop Applikationen</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 content-column">
            <img class="btn-center btn-webdesign" src="images/buttons/btn-webdesign.svg" alt="webdesign button">
            <h2 class="btn-webdesign-headline">Webdesign</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 content-column">
            <img class="btn-center btn-ios" src="images/buttons/btn-ios.svg" alt="ios Logo button">
            <h2 class="btn-ios-headline">iOS</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Now depending on the image size, the headlines move further down or not. How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any styling? CSS?

Comment: What do you expect to happen ? .... If the image is bigger then the text goes down and down . it is the normal behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to deal with this is that placing divs with full width and css specified heights. And while you get images from server side you should bind them in style attribute.

Advantage of doing this is that you can stretch images without messing aspect ratio and position it to center of div.